# Conflict with all namespaces and classes in file _ide_helper.php - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper - Laravel 5.6 PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

I have errors in the whole file with all namespaces and classes in  `_ide_helper.php`. I am using barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper 2.5.1 and Laravel 5.6.

[image]

From my composer.json:

```
 "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "2.5.1",
 "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
```

I added `Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class`  in `config/app.php`, but still is not working.

How to fix these errors?

Comment: 1) IDE version 2) What the errors are? What inspection generates those errors? I'm using one 2 month old project ("Generated for Laravel 5.6.33 on 2018-08-16 12:47:14" using "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.4.3") and it works just fine in PhpStorm 2018.2.5. The difference so far is that my methods are declared individually as real methods and not via PHPDoc `@method`.

Comment: OK .. upgraded to 2.5.1 -- got the same result. Apparently it included the same methods **twice** (e.g. `version()`: one as real method `public static function version()` and one as `@method static string version()`. So it must be an issue in  barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper -- either a bug or a config value. PhpStorm is correct here.